# When changing the image of a contact

Tags: objective-c, ios4, addressbook

I'm trying to change the image of a selected contact in `peoplePickerNavigationController`, but when I choose a contact, does not change the image and shows no error.

Well, far as I know, it's all right! Something is missing?

This is the code:

```
ABAddressBookRef aBook = ABAddressBookCreate();

UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"90x90.png"];
NSData *dataRef = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img);
CFDataRef cfdata = CFDataCreate(NULL, [dataRef bytes], [dataRef length]);
CFErrorRef error;

if(ABPersonRemoveImageData(person, &error)){
    NSLog(@"OK");
}
if(ABAddressBookSave(aBook, &error)){
    NSLog(@"OK");
}

if(ABPersonSetImageData(person, cfdata, &error)){
    NSLog(@"OK");
}
if(ABAddressBookSave(aBook, &error)){
    NSLog(@"OK");
}

CFRelease(cfdata);

[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
return NO;
```

Remembering that the above code is within the BOOL:

```
- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController: (ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person {  }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve, for those who have the same question in the future, just use the `ABRecordGetRecordID` and `ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID` and follows the code below:

```
ABAddressBookRef aBook = ABAddressBookCreate();

NSNumber *recordId = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:ABRecordGetRecordID(person)];
ABRecordRef pID = ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID(aBook,recordId.integerValue);

UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"90x90.png"];
NSData *dataRef = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img);
CFDataRef cfdata = CFDataCreate(NULL, [dataRef bytes], [dataRef length]);
CFErrorRef error;

ABPersonRemoveImageData(pID, &error);
ABAddressBookSave(aBook, &error);

ABPersonSetImageData(pID, cfdata, &error);
ABAddressBookSave(aBook, &error);

CFRelease(cfdata);

[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
return NO;
```

Thanks!